# Oracle with EntityFramework cause OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int16

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have a simple linQ expression

var list = db.MyEntity.Where(x=> x.fields == 'stringdata').toList();

At runtime,  this expression throw an exception:

```
[OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int16.]
       System.Convert.ToInt16(Int32 value) +6765512
       System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) +14182618
       Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.ChangeType(Object sourceValue, Type targetType) +810
       Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i) +4640
       System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) +229
       lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +3648
       System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly(Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet) +244
       lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +438
       System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) +383
```

My EntityFramework is bind on an Oracle Table. I suspect that a column got data larger than a Int16.

- Why does EntityFramework does not set the right type and or
  precision?
- Where and how can I fix this, edit the edmx manually?
- If I fix-It manually, will it be overwrite by the design the next time i
  update my edmx schema?

Comment: Generally this means the Data source and the C# class you're trying to bind to have conflicting data types. I.e. your C# class has an int, but the corresponding column is not an int. ---- Have you tried doing a FineOne() or First(), to see if it's not just random data but every row is wrong?

Comment: @mmcrae Nice one!  I will try that.  And now... I'm thinking about returning an anonymous type  new { field, field, field....}  maybe I can Isolate the field which cause the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it. I got columns which were defines as Number(5) in my Oracle Database. It's seem that EF map number(5) as Int16/Short integer type. But column with Number(5)  can hold value up to 99999 which is a lot greater then a 'short' integer.

So I edit my .edmx file manualy and my generate class to replace my Int16/Short type for Int32/long

Here's more documentation for custom Mapping Type with Oracle:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/entityDataTypeMapping.htm#ODPNT8303